# Парсер интернет магазина на Java

Tags: java, парсер

Получил тестовое задание написать парсер для интернет магазина, чтобы через поле поиска задать интересующий товар и на выходе получить xml файл со списком товара и его полями. Парсер должен имитировать человеческое поведение дабы не нарваться на бот-защиту.

Сам я начинающий и ничего подобного пока что не делал. Может, кто подскажет *алгортим действий (с библиотеками) или даст ссылку на подобную задачу*, где бы детально все объяснялось?

Comment: Можете попробовать, например, [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) или [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/), но с последним пунктом задания будет непросто.

Comment: `Парсер должен имитировать человеческое поведение дабы не нарваться на бот-защиту.` - такое ощущение, что вам дали не тестовое задание, а решили найти работника, которому не придется платить зарплату

Comment: @АлексейШиманский по общению, ребята показались адекватными, думаю, что просто ищут человека, который сможет потом делать необходимую работу)